# Loading local file with dataTaskWithURL throws unsupported url - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file

When I try to load a local file that I have saved to my device, it throws "unsupported url":

```
let filePath = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(myFileName)

NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: filePath)!) { (data, response, error) in
            completion(data: data, error: error)
            }.resume()



class func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

But when I use that same filePath, this returns true:

```
let checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(filePath)){ return true }
```

Comment: you need to use NSURL fileURLWithPath initialiser

Comment: btw why would you load asynchronously a local file resource?

Comment: NSURLSession is meant for downloading from the Internet. Perhaps you want something like `NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)`?

Comment: ah that's it, thank you!  I wanted to use this logic if the local file was large, which i agree if it's a local resource it shouldn't matter to most..  but i do not want the main thread being blocked.    Also, if i decide to offload some of the resources to a cdn i can re-use this logic which should be async :)